# Conditions for differentiation under integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let us have $f \in C^{(1)}[a,b]$, $g\in C[a,b]$, then:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{a}^{x}f(x)g(t)dt = \int_{a}^{x} \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}g(t)dt$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, write it as $$f(x)\int_a^x g(t)dt$$ and use the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus. You get 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\int_a^x g(t)dt\right)=f^\prime(x)\int_a^x g(t)dt+f(x)g(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you're trying to apply [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), remember that you have extra terms if the interval of integration is dependent on the differentiated variable.

Therefore,
\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{d x} \int_{a}^{\color{blue}{x}}f(x)g(t)dt &= \int_{a}^{x} \color{red}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}\left[f(x)g(t)\right]dt + \color{blue}{f(x)g(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(x)} \\
 &= \int_{a}^{x} \frac{d f(x)}{d x}g(t)dt + \color{blue}{f(x)g(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(x)} \\
  &= \int_{a}^{x} \frac{d f(x)}{d x}g(t)dt + \color{blue}{f(x)g(x)} \\
  &= f^\prime(x)\int_{a}^{x} g(t)dt + \color{blue}{f(x)g(x)}.
\end{align}

(Furthermore, you don't have partial derivatives here on the LHS, only within the integral.)